# testing is method is present using Rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm basically testing is method is present in the class but I can't make it work :(

My error-log is this one:

```
1) VideoSearch find the next video-sampler responds to find next video sampler
     Failure/Error: expect(vs).to respond_to(:find_next_sampler)
       expected #<VideoSearch:0x007faccb8a2300 @title=2345> to respond to :find_next_sampler
     # ./spec/models/video_search_spec.rb:41:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

My code:

```
class VideoSearch

  attr_accessor :title

  def initialize(params)
    @title = params

  end

  def self.find_next_sampler(end_time, end_point)
    Video.where("start_time >= ? AND start_point = ?" , "#{ end_time }", "#{ end_point }" ).first
  end

end
```

My spec:

```
  describe 'find the next video-sampler' do
    let(:v1) { v1 = Video.create( title: 2345 ) }
    let(:vs) { VideoSearch.new v1.title }

    it 'responds to find_next_sampler' do
      expect(vs).to respond_to(:find_next_sampler)

    end
```

Thanks very much 4 yr time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a class instance method. Instances of `VideoSearch` don't have this method, only the class itself does. So you should do this:

```
expect(VideoSearch).to respond_to(:find_next_sampler)
```

Comment: hi there! of course Sergio! wow Amazing what u learn or get focused when U'r doing Rspec lol, thanks alot!

Comment: You're welcome. A friendly piece of advice: try your best to write normal English. No textspeak.

Comment: I'll! I'm on mobile :) typing fast sometimes :) but sure!